# Rsync isn't creating parent folders

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a script that is rsync'ing folders. but rsync is not creating the parent directory.  `--dry-run` says folder is being created but when i remove `--dry-run` the script errors saying `failed: No such file or directory`.

```
image_source="/pi/home/data/pic/2019/05/*.png";
image_destination="/data/static/maps/2019/05";
rsync -hav --progress $image_source $image_destination;
```

Do I have to check the folder's existence first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rsync` will only create the final level of the directory hierarchy on the remote host if it's missing.

If you have multiple missing levels, you can precede it with a command like this:

```
$ ssh remote-host 'mkdir -p /data/static/maps/2019'
```

`rsync` will then be able to create the missing `05` level underneath that.